# how to prevent lock over the row. Insert works but update doesn't work

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, insert

The problem of my code is that I can insert properly into database, but if it will update, the connection times out. So to clarify my problem, My INSERT code works but the UPDATE doesn't.
I've already used sql transaction hence the data is still locked and i cannot update still.

Here is my code:

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim strConnString As String = DataSource.ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        Dim SQLStr As String

        Dim base64String = TextArea1.Value
        Dim imageBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String)
        Dim FileSizeOfIMG As String
        FileSizeOfIMG = imageBytes.Length
        Dim ImageTypeDataOfImage As New SqlParameter("@Data", SqlDbType.Image)
        ImageTypeDataOfImage.Value = imageBytes

        SQLStr = "SELECT 1 FROM [Patient_Data].[dbo].[tbPatientImage]   where HospNum='" & Session.Item("HospNum") & "' and IDNum='" & Session.Item("IDNum") & "' and FileType= '" & lblHeader.Text & "'"

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(SQLStr, con)
        cmd.Connection = con
        con.Open()
        Dim transaction As SqlTransaction

        transaction = con.BeginTransaction("MyTransaction")
        cmd.Transaction = transaction
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If reader.Read() Then
            SQLStr = "UPDATE [Patient_Data].[dbo].[tbPatientImage] SET PatImage= @Data, FileSize= '" & FileSizeOfIMG.ToString & "' , TransDate = GetDate() where HospNum='" & Session.Item("HospNum") & "' and IDNum='" & Session.Item("IDNum") & "' and FileType= '" & lblHeader.Text & "'  "
        Else

            SQLStr = "INSERT INTO [Patient_Data].[dbo].[tbPatientImage](HospNum,IDNum, DoctorID, PatImage , FileType, FileName, FileSize , TransDATE) " & _
                    " VALUES ('" & Session.Item("HospNum") & "','" & Session.Item("IDNum") & "', '" & Session.Item("DoctorID") & "', @Data, '" & lblHeader.Text & "', 'PatientPhoto' , '" & FileSizeOfIMG.ToString & "',  GETDATE())"
        End If
        reader.Close()
        cmd.CommandText = SQLStr
        cmd.Parameters.Add(ImageTypeDataOfImage)
        transaction.Commit()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        GetData()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: First things first, learn why and how to use parameterised queries. http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that you do have one parameter in there.  Why would you use one parameter and then string concatenation for everything else?  Just use parameters all the time and you can't go wrong.

Comment: Have you timed the insert?  Have you increased the command timeout and timed the update?

Comment: The insert works in just less than a second. And I am wondering why in some data, I can update it but some data i can only insert but not update.

Comment: I asked two questions.  You only provided one answer.

Comment: I have already used the parameters but the error still occur. And i used 1 parameter only for the image so that i can change its data type for inserting

Comment: That's not what I was talking about.  Using parameters is ALWAYS the proper thing to do but incidental to this issue, which is why I mentioned it separately.  I was talking about the fact that I asked " Have you increased the command timeout and timed the update" and you apparently ignored it.

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot. I think that is not the factor because even if i hardcode an update query directly on the database, it just loads forever.

Comment: Hmmm... in that case, it really doesn't have anything to do with VB.NET or ASP.NET and it's purely a SQL/database issue.  What data type is your column?  If it's `image` then can you change it to `varbinary`, which is preferred nowadays?  Have you tried with just small amounts of data and only updating some columns to see if it's some other column that's the issue?

Comment: i also think that the data type regarding the image is not the factor because Some data i can insert, and then it will update. I dont know why. I think its about data row lock on the database

Comment: I'm wondering why if i will insert dataA, and update it, connection times out. But if i will insert dataB and update it, it updates smoothly

Comment: Without knowing what dataA and dataB are, we can only guess.  Have you tried different sizes of data and noticed a particular size where things go haywire?  You need to do some thorough testing to try to discern a pattern.

Comment: whoa i changed the background and I made the same background the DataB on dataA and it updated. I think it is really on the size haha

Comment: how can i change its data size limit bigger?

Comment: At what size does the issue arise?  Remember that you don't have top save an actual image.  You can just save an array of all zeroes and just keep increasing the size by a small amount until it fails.  Again, have you tried increasing the timeout period on the command?

Comment: picture on Data A is 146KB(which is small already) and DataB is 4KB(which i can insert) I want to insert an image atleast 2MB

Comment: I haven't tried increasing timeout period.

Comment: @Dale, make sure you an index on columns specified in the `WHERE` clauses of the `UPDATE` statement.  Otherwise, a scan of the table will be needed and that is bad for performance and concurrency.  Also, use parameters and name sure the parameter data types match the data type of the underlying columns.

Comment: i had set a time out connection for my command to 2 mins but still no avail

Comment: @DanGuzman-SQLServerMVP do you know how to make the size of upload image larger?

Comment: @Dale, specify a parameter length of -1 for the image.  When you next see the problem, check the server for other queries that may be blocking the queries.

Comment: sir @DanGuzman-SQLServerMVP can you help me figure out? here is my new code in my new post. http://stackoverflow.com/q/25866018/3940478