# Can't UPDATE a large image size that was INSERTed in the database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, html5-canvas, upsert

Here is the problem, when I insert an image (let's call it Data A) which is 1.32MB, it will be inserted successfully. But if I will insert again Data A(but it will update now because i used UPSERT, see my code), it will not be updated and it will result to connection time out.

But when i insert another data (Data B) which is only 4KB, it will also be inserted successfully and if I will insert again into it(which is update), it will be updated successfully. What can I do? I cannot understand the problem. I already made my command timeout for 2 mins but nothing happened and it just loaded forever. I also used sql transaction but it did nothing.

Here is my code:

```
 Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim strConnString As String = DataSource.ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        Dim SQLStr As String

        Dim base64String = TextArea1.Value
        Dim imageBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String)
        Dim FileSizeOfIMG As String
        FileSizeOfIMG = imageBytes.Length
        Dim ImageTypeDataOfImage As New SqlParameter("@Data", SqlDbType.Image)
        ImageTypeDataOfImage.Value = imageBytes

        SQLStr = "SELECT 1 FROM [Patient_Data].[dbo].[tbPatientImage]   where HospNum='" & Session.Item("HospNum") & "'" & _
                " and IDNum='" & Session.Item("IDNum") & "' and FileType= '" & lblHeader.Text & "'"

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(SQLStr, con)
        cmd.Connection = con
        con.Open()

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If reader.Read() Then
            SQLStr = "UPDATE [Patient_Data].[dbo].[tbPatientImage] SET PatImage= @Data, FileSize= '" & FileSizeOfIMG.ToString & "' , TransDate = GetDate() where HospNum='" & Session.Item("HospNum") & "' and IDNum='" & Session.Item("IDNum") & "' and FileType= '" & lblHeader.Text & "'"
        Else
            SQLStr = "INSERT INTO [Patient_Data].[dbo].[tbPatientImage](HospNum,IDNum, DoctorID, PatImage , FileType, FileName, FileSize , TransDATE) " & _
                    " VALUES (@HospNum,@IDNum, @DoctorID, @Data, @FileType, 'Patient Photo' , @FileSize,  GETDATE())"
        End If
        reader.Close()
        cmd.CommandText = SQLStr    
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HospNum", Session.Item("HospNum"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDNum", Session.Item("IDNum"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DoctorID", Session.Item("DoctorID"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileType", lblHeader.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileSize", FileSizeOfIMG.ToString)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(ImageTypeDataOfImage)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        GetData()

    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: what is the error or profiler is saying ?

Comment: connection time out only, because when i update, it just loads.

Comment: uploading from local to local ? did you tried with <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180"/>

Comment: yes, i already tried adding that to web.config but still no avail. And even if i update directly on the sql server, it just loads forever.

Comment: when i insert greater than 7kb (i think) it will not be inserted because i tried inserting a 10kb file, it just loads.

Comment: any idea @codebased?

Comment: Honestly you will ahve to check various things at environment level. I am currently using ajax call to upload a file with 2 MB with no problem. You are mentioning about 10KB is the problem. You probably need to find out about the environment and update your question with the environment you are on. For e.g. are you using IIS. Check the size allowed there http://www.web-site-scripts.com/knowledge-base/article/AA-00696/0/Increasing-maximum-allowed-size-for-uploads-on-IIS7.html

Comment: You have mentioned above that you cannot upload more than 7 kb even directly to the SQL SERVER ? Please confirm. In that case the issue is with SQL table probably.

Comment: i tried updating other fields of the row, even if i will update the filename of the image, the database just loads.

Comment: If I insert the very FIRST image, no matter what the size is, it will be inserted, but if i will update already, no success. (If it is greater than 10kb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't figured out what causes this but i have figured out a remedy by having a delete query first then insert data.

```
   SQLStr = "delete FROM [Patient_Data].[dbo].[tbPatientImage]  where HospNum='" & Session.Item("HospNum") & "'" & _
            " and IDNum='" & Session.Item("IDNum") & "' and FileType= '" & lblHeader.Text & "'"

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(SQLStr, con)
        cmd.Connection = con
        con.Open()

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        SQLStr = "  INSERT INTO [Patient_Data].[dbo].[tbPatientImage](HospNum,IDNum, DoctorID, PatImage , FileType, FileName, FileSize , TransDATE) " & _
                " VALUES (@HospNum,@IDNum, @DoctorID, @Data, @FileType, 'Patient Photo' , @FileSize,  GETDATE())"

        cmd.CommandText = SQLStr
        'cmd.CommandTimeout = 120     
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HospNum", Session.Item("HospNum"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDNum", Session.Item("IDNum"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DoctorID", Session.Item("DoctorID"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileType", lblHeader.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileSize", FileSizeOfIMG)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(ImageTypeDataOfImage)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        GetData()
        lblMessage.Text = "Saved."

    End Using
End Sub
```